# Problems with QWidget in MDIchild - QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

In my open source project I want to add a sector scanner function. For this I tried to create a Widget similar to the of Defragment software products.
All is working expect the issue that I cannot bring the control scrollable. My code will always generate a forced size so the mdichild (parent) will resize and the scrolling is inside the MdiArea not inside the window. Means it will scroll the mdiHeader out of the view.

[image: With bigger MDIChild]

I expect that the control itself becomes scrollbars to scroll and the mdichild window will keep it size. My code is:

MDICHild: mdichild_scan.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "mdichild_scan.h"
#include "FoxSDKBurningLib.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "settingspages.h"
#include "messanger.h"

MdiChildScan::MdiChildScan(QWidget* parent, const QString &device)
    :strBurnDrive(device){
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    mProjectType = RuleManager::TYPE_PROJECT_DEVICEINFO;
    thisSuccessfullCreated = true;

    QString wTitle = tr("Hex ");
    wTitle += " (";
    wTitle += strBurnDrive;
    wTitle += ")";

    setWindowTitle(wTitle);

    QVBoxLayout * dlgSplitter = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QHBoxLayout * topNav = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QWidget * wdgSplitter = new QWidget(this);

    QLabel *labelTopNav = new QLabel(this);
    labelTopNav->setText(tr("This is a header"));
    topNav->addWidget(labelTopNav);
    topNav->setContentsMargins(1,8,1,0);

    dlgSplitter->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    dlgSplitter->setSpacing(0);
    dlgSplitter->setMargin(0);

    dlgSplitter->addLayout(topNav);

    scanBoard = new QScanBoard(45, 65);
    dlgSplitter->addWidget(scanBoard);



    wdgSplitter->setLayout(dlgSplitter);


    this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    this->setCentralWidget(wdgSplitter);


}
```

mdichild_scan.h

```
#ifndef MDICHILD_SCAN_H
#define MDICHILD_SCAN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QListView>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QLabel>
#include "mdichild_base.h"
#include "FoxSDKBurningLib.h"
#include "vrulemanager.h"
#include "QScanBoard.h"

class MdiChildScan : public MdiChildBase
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MdiChildScan(QWidget* parent, const QString &device);
    RuleManager::ProjectType GetProjectType() {return mProjectType;}
    bool thisSuccessfullCreated;

protected:
    RuleManager::ProjectType mProjectType;

    QString strBurnDrive;

private:
    QScanBoard* scanBoard;

};

#endif
```

The control itsel: QScanBoard.cpp

```
#include "QScanBoard.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QSet>

QScanBoard::QScanBoard(unsigned int numRows, unsigned int numCols, QWidget* parent)
    : QAbstractScrollArea(parent)
    , m_numRows(numRows)
    , m_numCols(numCols)
{
    setupLayout();
    createTiles();

}

void QScanBoard::setupLayout()
{
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect);
    this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    auto layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);

    setLayout(layout);

    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

    verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
}

void QScanBoard::createTiles()
{
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < m_numRows; ++r)
    {
        m_tiles += QList<QScanTile*>{};
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < m_numCols; ++c)
        {
            // add a new tile to the row
            m_tiles[r] += new QScanTile({ r, c }, this);
            static_cast<QGridLayout*>(this->layout())->addWidget(m_tiles[r][c], r, c);

        }
    }
    m_tiles[0][0]->setDown(true);

    viewport() -> update();
}
```

QScanBoard.h

```
#ifndef QSCANBOARD_H
#define QSCANBOARD_H

#pragma once
#include <QList>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QSet>
#include <QAbstractScrollArea>

#include "QScanTile.h"

class QScanBoard : public QAbstractScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QScanBoard(unsigned int numRows, unsigned int numCols, QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    unsigned int numCols() const { return m_numCols; }
    unsigned int numRows() const { return m_numRows; }


signals:

    void initialized();

private:

    void createTiles();
    void setupLayout();

private:

    unsigned int m_numRows;
    unsigned int m_numCols;

    QList<QList<QScanTile*>> m_tiles;

    QSet<QScanTile*> m_sectors;

};

#endif // QSCANBOARD_H
```

Progress Item: QScanTile.cpp

```
#include "QScanTile.h"

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QState>
#include <QFinalState>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QSizePolicy>

const QString QScanTile::unrevealedStyleSheet =
"QScanTile"
"{"
"   border: 1px solid darkgray;"
"   background: qradialgradient(cx : 0.4, cy : -0.1, fx : 0.4, fy : -0.1, radius : 1.35, stop : 0 #fff, stop: 1 #bbb);"
"   border - radius: 1px;"
"}";
const QString QScanTile::revealedStyleSheet =
"QScanTile"
"{"
"   border: 1px solid lightgray;"
"}";
const QString QScanTile::revealedWithNumberStylesheet =
"QScanTile"
"{"
"   color: %1;"
"   font-weight: bold;"
"   border: 1px solid lightgray;"
"}";

QIcon QScanTile::blankIcon()
{
    static QIcon icon = QIcon();
    return icon;
}

QScanTile::QScanTile(QScanTileLocation location, QWidget* parent /*= nullptr*/)
    : m_adjacentFlaggedCount(0)
    , m_location(location)
    , QPushButton(parent)
{
    this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    setCheckable(true);

    this->setIcon(blankIcon());
    this->setStyleSheet(unrevealedStyleSheet);
}

QScanTile::~QScanTile()
{

}



QScanTileLocation QScanTile::location() const
{
    return m_location;
}


QSize QScanTile::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(12, 12);
}
```

QScanTile.h

```
#ifndef QSCANTILE_H
#define QSCANTILE_H

#pragma once
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QList>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QState>
#include <QFinalState>
#include <QSignalMapper>

struct QScanTileLocation
{
    unsigned int row;
    unsigned int column;
};

class QScanTile : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    QScanTile(QScanTileLocation location, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~QScanTile() override;

    QScanTileLocation location() const;

    virtual QSize sizeHint() const override;

    static QIcon blankIcon();

private:
    QScanTileLocation m_location;

    static const QString unrevealedStyleSheet;
    static const QString revealedStyleSheet;
    static const QString revealedWithNumberStylesheet;

};

#endif // QSCANTILE_H
```

I hope someone can help me why the control will not get the expected scrollbars. (See in red)

[image: Expected scrollbars]

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. QAbstractArea was the wrong way. Now it works perfect.

Added a ScrollArea to the MDI Child and put the Control inside this

```
   scanBoard = new QScanBoard(200, 83);

    scrollArea->setWidget(scanBoard);
```

Control changed from QAbstractScrollArea to QFrame.